# YouTube Analytics: Day dimension aggregated by which timezone?

Tags: youtube-api

For YouTube Analytics API, there is a "day" dimension that can be used to break down metrics by day.

My question is

- What timezone is used in order to aggregate data into "day" buckets? The user's timezone or some fixed timezone like PST.
- Is DST handled properly with these daily aggregations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YouTube Analytics (and the API) uses the Pacific time zone (PDT/PST) for all reports, regardless of anything about the channel or the user running the report.

It does handle daylight savings time as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! What's the typical lag time for aggregations?  In other words, if I query for a report using the day dimension using a date range that ends with today, will I get data back for today?  Yesterday?  etc.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018142/latency-with-youtube-analytics-api

Comment: For people as confused as me: Is this just UTC-08:00 or do I need to observe daylight saving times?

Comment: It might be UTC-08:00 or UTC-07:00 depending on whether DST is in effect in the Pacific Time Zone. If you use a library to get the current time offsets for that time zone you should be fine.

Comment: Joda time [lists 9 time zones in UTC-8](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html). Which one would it be?

Comment: America/Los_Angeles should be fine.