# Youtube Analytics Updating Issue?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

Recently, i have been playing around with the youtube api. Every hour, i allow the the user to call the API for new data. There are two main metrics that i need.

- Yesterday's View
- Yesterday's Subscribers

Today, i made a GET request along the lines of this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==CHANNELID&start-date=2014-04-15&end-date=2014-04-15&metrics=views,subscribersGained&access_token=TOKEN-HERE
```

No rows are returned, meaning there is no data. If the API updates every 24 hours, should it not always return a value? The channel i do have linked has had subscribers and view this entire week, so i have no idea what might be the issue.

Yesterday i received values, but today i have not. So on April 14, there was data, April 15, there is none? That makes no sense.

When does the API update so i can configure my application with it?

**Update**

I have noticed on the most recent video, the stats (Analytics) on the video only go up to the 14th. If that is the case, would the API update every 48 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably already noted, the data is probably just not there yet. The API has the same data as YouTube Analytics webpage www.youtube.com/analytics

Jeff writes that a specific time when it's supose to be available is not given, but it is after midnight Pacific timezone, as that data is based on that timezone.

[Latency with Youtube Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018142/latency-with-youtube-analytics-api)

Answer (score -1):

Youtube Analytics updates every 2-5 days depending on if it is behind or not.  Normally it updates every 2 days.  Unfortunately Youtube Analytics has never and will never update every 24hours. You should check out this petition if you looking for a better program to check your channel statistics.

https://www.change.org/p/larry-page-sergey-brin-sundar-pichai-change-youtube-analytics-back-to-adsense