# Latency retrieving data from YouTube Analytics API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, analytics, latency, youtube-analytics

This question was asked and answered back in 2012, but things have changed and I'm looking for more of a concrete answer.

How much latency should I expect when accessing data from the YouTube Analytics API for the previous day? Note this is NOT the Data API. I'm not looking at feeds. I'm authenticating and requested views, averageDuration, likes, dislikes, etc from the Analytics API.

I'm in the Eastern timezone. I read that data for the previous day is "processed" some time after midnight Pacific time. I love that level of precision :-/  As of 8am eastern (5am pacific) and 10am eastern (7am pacific), I'm still getting zeros for the video metrics from yesterday.

Is there an official SLA/latency statement somewhere? If it's 36 hours or something, I'll be disappointed, but not angry. I just need to know the actual official word so that I can schedule this task to run at a reliable time every day.

This is part of a big analytics integration project. I appreciate any helpful input anyone can provide. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Latency with Youtube Analytics API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018142/latency-with-youtube-analytics-api)

Comment: The answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018142/latency-with-youtube-analytics-api still applies.