# How fresh is data from the YouTube Analytics API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

According to [Latency with Youtube Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018142/latency-with-youtube-analytics-api), data from the YouTube Analytics API should update daily. I'm trying to pull over time data for videos using the `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports` endpoint. To do this I'm sending parameters like the ones below:

`{
  'dimensions': 'day',
  'end-date': '2015-06-02',
  'filters': 'video==MY_VIDEO_ID',
  'ids': 'channel==MINE',
  'metrics': 'views,uniques,averageViewDuration,averageViewPercentage,comments,likes,dislikes,shares,subscribersGained,subscribersLost',
  'prettyPrint': 'false',
  'start-date': u'2013-03-18'
}`

I'm setting the `start-date` to the upload date of the video and the `end-date` to today, but I'm only getting data up to a couple days ago. For example that request above returns `2015-05-31` as the last date that data exists for. I have tried setting the `end-date` an additional day in the future in case the range was exclusive. According to [Latency with Youtube Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018142/latency-with-youtube-analytics-api) I should be getting data up to `2015-06-01`.

Is there an additional delay of an extra day now on the Analytics API? Is something wrong with my query? Is there a canonical page somewhere that has numbers for these delays similar to this [Adwords answer](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2544985)?

Comment: This is not a programming question and is better suited as a direct request to Google for information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018142/latency-with-youtube-analytics-api/13022480#13022480 lives as a question, and YouTube developers also check this tag. Additionally, I am not sure if there is something wrong with my query parameters. From those three things it seems like this can live as a question under the `youtube-api` tag.

Comment: Additionally [their support page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/support) points to the `youtube-analytics-api` tag on SO.

Comment: I'm also keen to get this question answered - I am experiencing the same thing today where I can only see views on a video back to the 31st Aug right now and it is 2 days after that now on the 2nd Sept. And this does seem to be the best place to ask it.